# Setup Ubuntu 22.04 go to the internet using loopback IP by default

Tags: networking, server, 22.04

I directly connect my Ubuntu 22.04 server to the router with 2 FC cables (bonding). The server and router will connect together with the subnet 10.27.28.5/30. I install my app in the container. I map this container with 1 IP public which set in the loopback interface.

Now I can ping to the IP public in loopback interface from the internet, but I cannot ping from the server to 8.8.8.8.
I still can traceroute to 8.8.8.8 with the source is the public IP although I cann't traceroute without source.

**ping 8.8.8.8**

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---

5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4087ms

**traceroute 8.8.8.8**

traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

1  _gateway (10.27.28.5)  1.602 ms  1.592 ms  1.609 ms

2  * * *

3  * * *

**traceroute 8.8.8.8 -s**

traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

1  _gateway (10.27.28.5)  1.600 ms  1.790 ms  1.943 ms

2  10.52.226.145 (10.52.226.145)  1.425 ms 10.52.226.149 (10.52.226.149)  1.570 ms  1.566 ms

...

13  * * *

14  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  45.061 ms  45.418 ms  45.377 ms

**I configure IP and routes by netplan**

'# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system

network:

version: 2

renderer: NetworkManager

ethernets:

```
  eno8403:

      dhcp4: false

      dhcp6: false

      dhcp4-overrides:

          use-routes: false

  eno8303:

      addresses: [10.52.17.251/29]

      routes:

          - to: 10.24.4.0/24

            via: 10.52.17.249

          - to: 10.24.5.0/24

            via: 10.52.17.249

          - to: 10.27.10.0/24

            via: 10.52.17.249

          - to: 10.27.11.0/24

            via: 10.52.17.249

      dhcp6: false

      dhcp4: false

      dhcp4-overrides:

          use-routes: false

  enp1s0f0np0:

      dhcp4: false

  enp1s0f1np1:

      dhcp4: false

  loop1:

      renderer: networkd

      dhcp4: false

      dhcp6: false

      addresses:

          - *.*.*.*/32

      dhcp4-overrides:

          use-routes: false
```

bonds:

```
  bond0:

      interfaces: [enp1s0f0np0,enp1s0f1np1]

      mtu: 9000

      parameters:

          mode: balance-rr

          mii-monitor-interval: 100

      addresses:

          - 10.27.28.6/30

      routes:

          - to: default

            via: 10.27.28.5
```

**IP route table**

default via 10.27.28.5 dev bond0 proto static metric 20300

10.24.4.0/24 via 10.52.17.249 dev eno8303 proto static metric 100

10.24.5.0/24 via 10.52.17.249 dev eno8303 proto static metric 100

10.27.10.0/24 via 10.52.17.249 dev eno8303 proto static metric 100

10.27.11.0/24 via 10.52.17.249 dev eno8303 proto static metric 100

10.27.28.4/30 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 10.27.28.6 metric 300

10.52.17.248/29 dev eno8303 proto kernel scope link src 10.52.17.251 metric 100

169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000

172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1

So how can I set default go to the internet with IP public. I check app can go to the internet but the server itself cannot, so I can update packet for it.